# Azure API management Security

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am working with azure API management and struggling on authentication.
Though subscriber key is an option but the question lies like if there are going to be 100's of users it will be very difficult to manage keys of all users
Also I dont want azure AD  as an authentication mechanism. 
I want to use security provided by API management.
I also tried with token based approach of API management but the thing is it do requires subscriber key in the headers. If I want to get rid of subscriber key
what is the best option ?

Comment: I am not sure what is token based approach but you can disable "Require Subscription" option under product => Settings